# What does share of equity mean?

Tags: united-states, stocks, accounting

The following is from Exxon Mobil's website which can be found at:
[Exxon Mobil's Balance Sheet](https://investor.exxonmobil.com/earnings/balance-sheet)

It has the following line in it:
Exxon Mobil share of equity       199,703              195,049

What do they mean by Exxon Mobile share of equity? Does it have anything to do with the treasury stock it is currently holding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the sum of the 4 rows above it, so it *includes* treasury shares.  It is essentially the equity attributable solely to Exxon, not its subsidiaries in which it does not own a controlling interest.

The Total equity also includes the equity Exxon has in non-controlling subsidiaries.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still learning about finance, but it seems 'share of equity' reflects a company's ownership in assets or subsidiaries. Treasury stock, bought back by the company, isn't directly linked to calculating ownership. The equity share represents the company's stake in other ventures, impacting its financial standing. This ownership can greatly affect Exxon Mobil's overall financial status and potential profits.